# Proper ViewModel initialization using arguments between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, arguments, fragment, viewmodel

This [example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/index.html#7) shows the ViewModel usage and how to create a ViewModelFactory to initialize a ViewModel passing one argument. At the end of the example there is a note saying:

`Note: In this app, it's not necessary to add a ViewModelFactory for the ScoreViewModel, because you can assign the score directly to the viewModel.score variable. But sometimes you need the data right when the viewModel is initialized.`

In fact, in order to populate the final score of the `ScoreFragment` it says to do the following

```
binding.scoreText.text = viewModel.score.toString()
```

but, isn't it incorrect? Shouldn't the `binding.scoreText.text` be assigned with `viewModel.score.value.toString()`? And how can you avoid using the ViewModelFactory to properly initialize the `finalScore` variable inside the `ScoreFragmentViewModel` by using the argument provided by the `GameFragment` when the game is ended? Since the `ScoreFragment` is only showing the final score without making any changes, why in the final code example has been added an observer in the `onCreateView` of the `ScoreFragment`?

```
    // Add observer for score
    viewModel.score.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { newScore ->
        binding.scoreText.text = newScore.toString()
    })
```

I also have another simple question.
Assuming that I have two fragments, the first simply showing a couple of TextViews and the second one meant to edit them, so the second fragment is the only one capable of modifying the underlying model, is it necessary to create two ViewModels? The second fragment should be initialized with the TextViews of the calling fragment, is implementing a ViewModelFactory to initialize those fields strictly necessary or is there a simplier mechanism to initialize them?

Answer (score 0):

The example you mentioned of course is rather educational and maybe it's not similar to real projects. I'll try to give my thoughts as to your questions:

1. ScoreViewModel in the example holds just one value and it's really never changes. So there is no need to observe it changes, that's why this value is not LiveData and there is no need to use

   `viewModel.score.value.toString()`
2. You can skip ViewModelFactory if your ViewModel doesn't have parameters in constructor. So you can make your ScoreViewModel with no parameters, but to use some kind of public setter for field "score" (and set it from ScoreFragment with final score from the bundle). It maybe not the recommended way in some cases. I think they wrote that note to emphasise the different scenarios you can use to initialise ViewModel. Maybe it was not very elegant way :-)
3. I couldn't find using next code you mentioned (it shouldn't be there because "score" couldn't be observed)

   `viewModel.score.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { newScore ->
       binding.scoreText.text = newScore.toString()
   })`
4. As to the two fragments your question is not clear. If you want they share some scope of data (the same data), you can use [shared ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing). For example, that shared ViewModel can hold two LiveData-strings, then first fragment can just "show" these strings (TextViews whatever), and the second fragment can "edit" them